# Passing parameters to the constructor to an object (Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, parameters, constructor, arguments

I am working on a side-scrolling platformer game. Because of this, I have a class that acts as a floor.  I also have a class representing enemies.

I am having problems with passing a parameter to a custom class' constructor. The class (SkullDemon.as) extends MovieClip.  I am trying to pass an instance (called "floorL1") of a customer class called "FloorLevel1." "FloorLevel1" also extends MovieClip (I do not have a written .as file for "FloorLevel1"; I just exported the floor MovieClip to that class).

I am trying to pass an instance of "FloorLevel1" so that the "SkullDemon" object can land on the floor just like in a platformer.

My main class is called "TME2_Main."  This is the class from which I try to pass the "floorL1" instance to the "SkullDemon" class.  This is how I try to create a Skull Demon instance and pass "floorL1" to its constructor:

```
skullD1 = new SkullDemon(floorL1);
```

I try to create the SkullDemon within "TME2_Main's" constructor.

Here is the "SkullDemon" class' constructor :

```
        // Constructor (takes in Level 1's floor variable as an argument
    public function SkullDemon(floorL1:FloorLevel1) {
    //public function SkullDemon() {
        // Move the Skull Demon as soon as it is created
        moveSkullDemon();

    }
```

I get two types of errors when I run the .swf:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on SkullDemon(). Expected 1, got 0.
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at TME2d_Main()

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
at flash.display::Stage/addChild()
at TME2d_Main()
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I have spent a while looking for solutions (including moving code outside of TME2_Main's constructor), but nothing has really helped me so far.

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening at the creation of Skull Demon specified? The error is saying it's expecting an argument but not getting one. It looks like it's happening on the TME2*d*_Main() class.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I am confused! :P If I remove the parameter from the call to the SkullDemon constructor and remove the parameter from the SkullDemon class' constructor, there is no error.

Comment: Do you have another call somewhere else to the SkullDemon constructor? I guess I'm confused as to why you're saying the error is happening in the TME2_Main class and yet the stack trace is showing TME2d_Main.

Comment: Could you turn on the debugger? That would give you the exact line where the error is happening. Based on the code you've pasted, there's obviously nothing wrong with your constructor or the way you create your object. We either need to see more code or proper error messages.

Comment: Sorry, all for my late response. I was dealing with other problems in my program. I have actually been able to fix this problem with lots of help from users in another thread. Here is that thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882235/actionscript-3-0-activating-eventlistener-for-an-object

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an instance of SkullDemon somewhere on the stage. If you do, Flash will attempt to call the constructor for SkullDemon without passing any arguments. You can usually tell this is the problem when it happens in the Sprite class's constructChildren() method.