# Actionscript 3.0 Activating EventListener for an Object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, object, event-listener

In my Flash program, I am trying to run a function within an object. The object uses a class called "SkullDemon.as." The function I am trying to run is called "moveSkullDemon();" this function is coded within the "SkullDemon.as" class.

My main document class is "TME2d_Main.as." Within that file I create an instance of the Skull Demon class like this:

```
        public var skullD1b:SkullDemon;
        skullD1b = new SkullDemon();
        skullD1b.x = 2990.75;
        skullD1b.y = 836.95;
        skullDemonContainer.addChild(skullD1b);
```

The 'skullDemonContainer', which stores the SkullDemon instances, is placed into another container, called 'envContainer,' which is added to the screen using this line of code:

```
        this.addChild(envContainer);
```

The SkullDemon instance is created and loads onto the screen just fine. The problem occurs when I try to run any function within the SkullDemon class.

As mentioned before, I try to call the 'SkullDemon.moveSkullDemon()' function for the 'skullD1b' instance. For now, the 'moveSkullDemon()' function just moves the SkullDemon object to the left.

I tried calling this function from the SkullDemon's constructor function, but that does not work. In fact, any code written within the SkullDemon's constructor is not executed when a Skull Demon object is created. I have tried to create an EventListener within the SkullDemon class that calls 'moveSkullDemon(),' but that does nothing.

I have tried the following methods to get the 'moveSkullDemon()' function to run:

1: Calling 'moveSkullDemon()' from 'TME2d_Main' like this:

```
skullD1b.moveSkullDemon();
```

But this brings up an error (#1006), saying that 'moveSkullDemon' is not a function.

2: Doing the same thing as #1 except that I have no parenthesis within the function call:

```
skullD1b.moveSkullDemon;
```

3: Creating an EventListener within 'TME2d_Main' for the 'skullD1b' instance that calls its 'moveSkullDemon' function:

```
skullD1b.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, skullD1b.moveSkullDemon);
```

This brings up another error: "Error #2007: Parameter listener must be non-null."  It also constantly finds a "null" reference error:

```
    "1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at classes::TME2d_Main/controlPlayer()"
```

I do not know why this problem refers to the 'controlPlayer()' method, as it does not involve the Skull Demon instance at all. 'controlPlayer()' is called through an EventListener with this code within 'TME2d_Main':

```
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, controlPlayer);
```

4: Creating an EventListener for the 'SkullDemonContainer' that calls the move function:

```
skullDemonContainer.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, skullD1b.moveSkullDemon);
```

This brings up the same error as in #3.

I have been having this problem for a few days now and do not know what is causing it. Here is my code within the 'moveSkullDemon()' function:

```
        public function moveSkullDemon() {
        trace("skull demon moving!");

        this.x -= 5;

        // If the Player has not hit the 'floor,' increase his falling 
            //speed
        if (! floor.hitTestPoint(this.x, this.y, true)) {
            this.y += this.sdGravity;
            // The Skull Demon is not on the ground when he's not touching it
            sdOnGround = false;
        }

        // Increase the 'sdYVel' variable so that the Skull Demon will fall 
            // progressively faster down the screen. This code technically
            // runs "all the time" but in reality it only affects the Skull Demon
            // when he's off the ground.
        sdYVel += sdGravity;            

        // Increase the Skull Demon's 'y' coordinate by the 'sdYVel' value
        if (! sdOnGround) {
            this.y += sdYVel;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help you may offer.

Comment: I should mention that calling 'moveSkullDemon()' from within the constructor for 'SkullDemon.as' worked before I used a package-style system for my project. Certain circumstances forced me to use the project system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you are attempting to dispatch an event against your display object, therefore calling a function?

When you instantiate your skull demon object, add an event listener for the type of event you wish to handle.  For example, if you created a "DemonEvent" class:

```
// instantiate and add event listener:
skullD1b = new SkullDemon();
skullD1b.addEventListener(DemonEvent.MOVE, moveDemonHandler);
```

When you want to call the "moveDemonHandler" function, you dispatch an event against the object:

```
// do call this event listener, dispatch an event
// against the object
skullD1b.dispatchEvent(new DemonEvent(DemonEvent.MOVE));
```

You can place code within the event handler, or call your function from the event handler code:

```
    protected function moveDemonHandler(event:DemonEvent):void
    {
        moveSkullDemon();
    }

    protected function moveSkullDemon():void
    {
        // ... your code here.
    }
```

Example "DemonEvent" if you need:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class DemonEvent extends Event
    {

        public static const MOVE:String = "MOVE";

        public function DemonEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based upon your comment, it sounds like you are determining the best place to put code to move your object.  Your skull demon could move itself, or since your TME2d_Main class adds the skull demon, positions it initially, and because you need to hit test against a floor, it might make more sense to put that logic in the TME2d_Main class.

This example doesn't use events; however, hopefully helps you get started.  Let me know if you'd rather have an example that uses events instead.

here are two classes as an example implementation:

TME2d_Main.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TME2d_Main extends Sprite
    {
        /** skull demon instance */
        public var skullD1b:SkullDemon;

        /** floor */
        public var floor:Sprite;

        /** constructor */
        public function TME2d_Main()
        {
            super();

            // best if implemented on addedToStage
            skullD1b = new SkullDemon();
            skullD1b.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
            skullD1b.y = 1;
            addChild(skullD1b);

            // listen for enter frame
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        /** every frame, move skull demon */
        protected function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            // call local function of this class
            moveSkullDemon();
        }

        protected function moveSkullDemon():void
        {
            // since this TME2d_Main class defined and positioned
            // skullD1b, it probably makes sense for this class
            // to continue positioning it, especially if you need to
            // hit test again a floor, which is probably also defined
            // in this class?
            if (skullD1b.hitTestObject(floor))
            {
                // skull is on floor 
                skullD1b.sdOnGround = true;

                // end animation
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            }
            else
            {
                // otherwise, skull is in air and falling
                skullD1b.y *= skullD1b.sdYVel;
            }
        }

        // if you wanted to have skull demon
        // move itself, you would call:
        //
        //     skullD1b.moveSkullDemon()
        //
        // ...but make sure that function exists
        // in SkullDemon class.

    }
}
```

SkullDemon.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class SkullDemon extends Sprite
    {

        /** acceleration factor */
        public var sdYVel:Number = 1.05;

        /** whether skull demon is on ground */
        public var sdOnGround:Boolean = false;

        /** constructor */
        public function SkullDemon()
        {
            super();
        }

        // if you want SkullDemon to move itself,
        // make sure you define a moveSkullDemon function:
        //
        //      public function moveSkullDemon():void
        //      {
        //      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Jason! I have implemented the code you have suggested. However, I still have a question. Where do I place the 'moveDemonHandler()' function? I am assuming this would go into the 'SkullDemon' class (?). I tried this at first, but then when I get to this line:
 
'skullD1b.addEventListener(DemonEvent.MOVE, moveDemonHandler);' 

the compiler complains, finding this error: 

"1180: Call to a possibly undefined method moveDemonHandler'. 

I tried putting the handler and moveDemon() code into 'DemonEvent,' but that didn't work well at all.

Comment: I think TME2d_Main where your container is looks like it dispatches and listens for the event, but SkillDemon class has the moveSkullDemon function in it.  Depends on if you want TME2d_Main to move your skull demon or if you want the skull demon object to move itself.  Let me try to improve my answer now that I better understand your question.

Comment: That works, Jason! Thanks again. I do have one more question. Sorry about that; I am learning Flash on the spot.

I implemented almost exactly your updated code. I did, however, change the 'moveDemon' function to iteratively move every single Skull Demon within the SkullDemonContainer. I used a while loop to do this.

When I load 10 Skull Demons, the program seems to run at a good speed. My question is if there is a more optimal way to do this? I tried passing the 'current' demon object as an argument to the 'enterFrameHandler', but it seems to work only if the 'event' is passed.

Comment: Using a loop makes sense, you could use while or a "for each(var demon:SkullDemon in skullDemonArray" or "for(var i:uint = 0; i < skullDemonContainer.numChildren; i++) { var demon:SkullDemon = skullDemonContainer.getChildAt(i); }".  I think you've got good traction, though - excellent!

Answer (score 0):

in your TME2d_Main.as file you state you your code is like so.

```
    public var skullD1b:SkullDemon;
    skullD1b = new SkullDemon();
    skullD1b.x = 2990.75;
    skullD1b.y = 836.95;
    skullDemonContainer.addChild(skullD1b);
```

The last 4 lines need to be put in a function. You can not instantiate or assign values in a class outside of a function. 
Well you can instantiate like so, but all other code needs to be functionalized(is that even a word).

```
public var skullD1b:SkullDemon = new SkullDemon();

// TME2d_Main is the constructor and should be called automatically
public function TME2d_Main( ):void{
    skullD1b.x = 2990.75;
    skullD1b.y = 836.95;
    skullDemonContainer.addChild(skullD1b);
}
```

Your best bet is to do this.

```
public var skullD1b:SkullDemon;

// TME2d_Main is the constructor and should be called automatically
public function TME2d_Main( ):void{
    skullD1b = new SkullDemon();
    skullD1b.x = 2990.75;
    skullD1b.y = 836.95;
    skullDemonContainer.addChild(skullD1b);
}
```

If this doesn't fix it then post your full TME2d_Main.as file.

Comment: Sorry, I did not copy my code correctly. I have my 'TME2d_Main.as' file set up like the way suggest, but I did not reflect that in my post with a "...".

Comment: Well, I don't think you will get good help if you do not post the TME2d_Main.as Anything at this point is just guess work. Just edit your question and post it. You have a scoping issue and we can't find it without that code.